# zip a list of files at command-line linux

Tags: zip, php-ziparchive

If I have a list of files I want to zip, how can I pass the list to zip?

```
cookbook/application/views/index.php
cookbook/application/controller/index.php
cookbook/js/index.js
....
cookbook/css/index.css
```

To do the above list one by one at the command-line would be like `zip -r my.zip cookbook/css/index.css`, where `my.zip` is in the same root directory as `cookbook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
zip -r@ my.zip < listfile
```

The `-@` flag tells `zip` to read file names from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

If all files are in the same folder, you don't need to type each file that you want to include in the archive. Just invoke the command and specify their common folder like this:

zip -r cookbook.zip cookbook

All files inside the cookbook directory will be included in the zip archive.

Comment: yes, documentation is easy to find for that method, all files in a directory and below.  But I am doing a select list as it is a plug-in for Codeigniter that I want people to test.  My whole distro of CI is not being shared; only the files of the plug-in